# Combining two csv files into one csv file in pentaho spoon

Tags: csv, pentaho, etl

I want to combine multiple CSV files into one CSV file in pentaho spoon. 
for e.g

file1.txt has values

Name,Address

abc,pune

file2.txt has values

Email,age

abc@gmail.com,25

Now i want output to be in one csv file

Name,Address,Email,Age

Please help me with this..

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the Pentaho PDI / Kettle documentation?

Comment: Yes I have tried with text file input and then select values.. but i am getting all the values in one column only..

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the [Merge Join](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Merge+Join) step.

In order to combine the data from two different data streams, they need to have a common key to join on, so I'd suggest using a field like "ID" or similar.

Merge Join will only need to have the Key fields of the IDs coming in from the csv files. Then you can pass the data to a text file output, and exclude the ID, if you don't want it in the final result.

### My test data (edit Join type as necessary)

**file1.txt**

```
Id,Name,Address
1,abc,Washington
2,Noah,Philadelphia
```

**file2.txt**

```
Id,Email,Age
1,e@mail.me,25
2,noah@email,50
```

**results.txt**

```
Name,Address,Email,Age
abc,Washington,e@mail.me,25
Noah,Philadelphia,noah@email,50
```

**Transformation Setup**
[image: Transformation Setup]

**Merge Join step**

[image: Merge2]

Comment: Be aware that the `Merge Join` step requires data from both input paths be sorted ascending by the join key. In your example, if the data in your text files isn't already sorted, you won't get correct results.